# Can't add a comment with a button Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, button, comments

I have this function in functions.php:

```
function voteaza_lucrare()
{
        if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) 
        {
            $id_post = $_REQUEST['id1'];

            $time = current_time('mysql');
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            $data = array(
                'comment_post_ID' => $id_post,
                'comment_author' => $current_user->user_login,
                'comment_author_email' => $current_user->user_email,
                'comment_author_url' => 'http://startut.ro',
                'comment_content' => 'Vot ',
                'comment_type' => '',
                'comment_parent' => 0,
                'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
                'comment_author_IP' => '127.0.0.1',
                'comment_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
                'comment_date' => $time,
                'comment_approved' => 1,
            );

            wp_insert_comment($data);

            echo $id_post;
        }
        die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_voteaza_lucrare', 'voteaza_lucrare' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_voteaza_lucrare', 'voteaza_lucrare' );
```

This function will add a comment to a post, work perfect, but...

I try to use this function in comment-template.php for the link of a button using ajax request:

```
<div style="float: right;"><a onclick="add_comment('<?php echo $id ; ?>')" href="#" class="button facebook"><font color="#ffffff">Voteaz&#259; aceast&#259; lucrare</font></a></div>
```

And the function for ajax request is:

```
<script>
        function add_comment(id)
        {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

                $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'voteaza_lucrare',
                    'id1' : id
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
                });
            }); 
        }
    </script>
```

The code add the comment, this is the resolvation if anyone will have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way.

```
<?php 
$id = get_the_ID();
?>

<div style="float: right;"><a onclick="add_comment('<?php echo $id ; ?>')" class="button facebook"><font color="#ffffff">Votează această lucrare</font></a></div>

<script>

function add_comment(id)
{
  //send ajax request in wp with 'id' as data .
}
</script>
```

Then in the ajax request execute your php code to add a comment to your post.

If you are not familiar with using ajax in WP have a look at this simple example.

EDIT :

Notice the slight modification.

```
<script>
function add_comment(id)
{
 var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

                $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'voteaza_lucrare',
                     'id1' : id
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: And in function in script, how can I use php to work with variables as $current_user->user_login ? Or the function is the same.

Comment: You need to send an ajax request through the js function. When ajax call is received by php it will do the rest of the work.

Comment: the php function which you call with an ajx request can easily get the current user email , pass and id etc , with this `wp_get_current_user()` . So you don't need to pass it through ajax. DId you get the point. ?

Comment: Where is the PHP part .  Haven't you gone through this link .
http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

Comment: I try, but is my first time with ajax request, the php code is in functions.php in wp-include/functions.php.

Comment: It is supposed to be in your theme's function.php. Also show that as well.

Comment: But Javascript piece is in comment-template.php in wp-include/comment-template.php, so the PHP piece still need to be in theme's functions.php ?

Comment: I put the PHP piece in theme's functions.php (wp-content/themes/ThemeName/functions.php), but still, nothing happens.

Comment: Show that as well , so I could tell you the mistake.

Comment: Please, tell me, I add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_voteaza_lucrare', 'voteaza_lucrare' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_voteaza_lucrare', 'voteaza_lucrare' );` , but still don't work.

Comment: I edit the question with the new changes, I forgot `echo $id_post;` and `die();` but still don't work.

Comment: I've edited my ans . Make sure you open your console and track your ajax request , to make sure it sends the request successfully.

Comment: In console tell me this: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
add_comment
onclick` , so the request is not sended.

Comment: I resolve the problem, thanks man, the solving is in my question, I edit it.